# Cannot execute a php file when included in another file but executes when opened as standalone file

Tags: php

I have two php files called my_profile.php in two different folders: backend and frontend.

Root folder has 2 folders called frontend and backend. Frontend folder has 1 file my_profile.php. And backend folder has 2 files my_profile.php and connection.php.

The code in backend/my_profile.php is

```
    <?php
    require_once './connection.php';
    $credit_score=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT credits FROM volunteers WHERE username='$user';");
    $credit=mysqli_fetch_assoc($credit_score);
    $credits=$credit['credits'];
    return $credits;
```

The code in backend/connection.php is

```
<?php
error_reporting (0);
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","vector");
?>
```

The code in frontend/my_prohile.php is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <?php require_once '../backend/my_profile.php'; ?>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My Profile</title>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- View credit score -->
    <p>Your credits: <?php echo($credits)?></p>

</body>
</html>
```

When I run backend/my_profile.php: I get the output as a number (i.e., value of $credits). But when I run frontend/my_profile.php: I get the error *Notice: Undefined variable: conn in G:\ROHAN\eTh0\VectorVolunteers\backend\my_profile.php on line 4*. Why is this so?

(pls note that $user has been included in another file as $_SESSION['user'] and that works fine...)

Comment: Did you check/debug `$conn` using `var_dump()` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 4 of frontend/my_profile.php, you call '../backend/my_profile.php'.

Then this my_profile.php will require './connection.php' in the same directory than my_profile.php, ie **frontend** directory that does not contain connection.php.

Comment: Is there any way that I can use this folder structure as it is without adding connection.php to frontend folder?? This would be great help...

Comment: If that is the case wouldn't 'require_once' throw an error? Since connection.php does not exist as you say then wouldn't 'require_once' throw an error?

Comment: @RohanShah You could change your current working directory to backend with chdir('../backend');